# Hive gives error when trying to find record with min subquery

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

In hive,

I am trying to select the entry with the minimum timestamp, however it's throwing the following error, not sure what is the reason.

```
select * from sales where partition_batch_ts = (select max(partition_batch_ts) from sales);
```

**Error**

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:91 cannot recognize input near 'select' 'max' '(' in expression specification

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use proper table alias. Also, `IN` must be used instead of `=`

```
SELECT s1.*
FROM sales s1
WHERE s1.partition_batch_ts IN
    (SELECT MAX(partition_batch_ts)
     FROM sales s2);
```

From Hive manual, [**SUBQUERIES**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries) :

> As of Hive 0.13 some types of subqueries are supported in the WHERE
>   clause.